# WebView not started javascript

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have some fragment with WebView. Webview launches the link, but only partially. Clicks on buttons do not work out and part of the interface does not load. I have similar code in another application and everything works correctly there.

```
class SomeFragment  {

    //Some code

    //This method invoke in onViewCreated
    override fun initView() {
       //some code
        initWebView()
    }

    //This method invoked by presenter
    //reference is correct, i checked it
    override fun updateView(reference: String, mimeType: String, encoding: String) =
        webView.loadData(reference, mimeType, encoding)

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun initWebView() {
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.webViewClient = CustomWebClient()
    }

    private inner class CustomWebClient : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            return if (url.contains("google")) {
                true
            } else super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/view_header_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <View
        style="@style/ShadowPopupHorizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the desired result.

[image]

And this is the result

[image]

Comment: Whenever there is an issue in WebView, you should not forget to do remote debugging. This will rule out if issue is with the web content.

Comment: I have 2 applications. One network request. In one application this works correctly, in the second not. At the same time, there are no differences in the code that relates specifically to WebView. Apparently I’m missing a trifle, but I can’t understand which one.